# On a AC to DC adapter there are +12v wire with 24A and -12v have 0.5A. How many amp this adapter will provide in total?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

I have a PSU of a pc which is 500w. I want to charge a 12v 100ah battery which need 20 amp of current. Is this psu can provide current that I have wanted?

Main question is

On a AC to DC adapter (PSU) there are +12v wire with 24A and -12v have 0.5A. How many amp this adapter will provide in total?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to charge a 12v 100ah battery which need 20 amp of current.

You can charge the battery at any current proving it is not too high and it might be that the 20 amp is the maximum charging current?

If the adapter gives a constant (regulated) 12 volts then you will not be able to charge a battery of the lead-acid type it will require more than 12 V to drive current through it.

I would not recommend putting 24 V across the 12 V battery without a series resistor as that will damage it and might even cause an explosion.

With the appropriate series resistor the maximum current will be the 0.5 A.

If you want to charge at 0.5 A with a series resistor then the resistor needs to have an appropriate power rating.
Given that the resistor will have a voltage of about 10 volts across it and a current of 0.5 amps through it it must be rated at greater than 5 W.

Rather than damage the pc power supply, the 12 V battery and yourself, I suggest you obtain a custom built battery charger.